# Hovering on Div

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and need a help please. I am trying to get the content of the following div to appear when I hover on it, here is a snippet of my code.

```js
const currentTab = await Logic.currentTab();
const currentPage = document.getElementById("current-page");
currentPage.innerHTML = `<span class="page-title truncate-text">${currentTab.title}</span>`;
const favIconElement = Utils.createFavIconElement(currentTab.favIconUrl || "");
currentPage.prepend(favIconElement);
```

```css
#current-tab img {
max-block-size: var(--icon-size);
}
#current-page{
  display: table-cell;
}
#current-tab .page-title {
  font-size: var(--font-size-heading);
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
}
```

```html
<span><div id="current-page"></div></span>
```

Comment: Is it important that this be accomplished with JS?  The best/cleanest/recommended approach to achieve this effect would generally be in [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58443502/hovering-on-div#58443551) in @bresleveloper 's answer.  However, it *can* be accomplished with JS if that is a requirement.

Comment: Yes I tried solving this with CSS, but when I hover on the div, I still get nothing. So I tried the solution with JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Intial Answer**

Javascript,

```
document.getElementById("current-page").addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
   e.target.innerHTML = "change text";
});
```

jQuery,

```
$('#current-page').hover(function(){
    $(this).html("change text")
})
```

Working sample: https://jsbin.com/yomeyesuxu/edit?html,css,js,output

**Tooltip**

You can follow something like this,

```js
$('#current-page').hover(function(){
   $(this).find('.page-title').toggle()
})
```

```css
.page-title {
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  display: none
}

#current-page {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="current-page">
  hover on me
  <span class='page-title truncate-text'>Test</span>
</div>
```

Only CSS,

```css
.page-title {
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  display: none
}

#current-page {
  position: relative;
}

#current-page:hover .page-title {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="current-page">
  hover on me
  <span class='page-title truncate-text'>Test</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I get the title now when I hover, but can I not get the title as a tooltip instead of replacing the div?

Comment: @Sara do you use any tooltip plugin ?

Comment: No I did not use any tooltip plugin. Do I need to? @Casper

Comment: @Sara not really.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, it is working now. @Casper

Comment: Excuse me, can you please tell me how do I make the span value varies according to the div value? I mean I want the span to get the value of the div, so how can I do that? @Casper

Comment: $(this).find('.page-title').html($(this).html()).toggle()

Answer (score 3):

With css you should be done with the hide/show logic, with us just populate the div

```
#current-page{
  display: none;
}
#current-page:hover{
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this but when I hover I still get nothing. Thanks for your reply.